# Very fast logging in multi-threaded environment in java

Tags: logging, log4j, java.util.logging, log4j2

I tried `logj4`, setting bufferedIO to true, asynappender, but the last about 100 lines of logs are missed.

What would be the better technique for logging in a multi-threaded environment in java, where we have to do logging at a very fast rate?

We are logging around 330MB in around 20 seconds..and clearly we can see that the logging is stopped in between. The last line is 4094902:[11, 12, 17, 14, 15, 16, 13, 10, 3, 
where there should be abt 200 lines more

Comment: Lines are missed? Are u dispatching logs into syslog? If so, you certainly use UDP.

Comment: Logging in a local text file.

Comment: Logger rootLogger = Logger.getRootLogger();
rootLogger.setLevel(Level.INFO);
PatternLayout layout = new PatternLayout("%m%n");
RollingFileAppender fileAppender = new RollingFileAppender(layout, "somefile.log");
fileAppender.setAppend(false);
fileAppender.setMaxFileSize("25MB");
fileAppender.setMaxBackupIndex(100);
fileAppender.setImmediateFlush(false);
fileAppender.setBufferedIO(true);
rootLogger.addAppender(fileAppender);

Comment: configuring it programmatically as above...

Comment: No idea, but that interrest me

Comment: We are logging around 330MB in around 20 seconds..and clearly we can see that the logging is stopped in between. The last line is  4094902:[11, 12, 17, 14, 15, 16, 13, 10, 3, where there should be abt 200 lines more

Answer (score 3):

You may be interested in Async Loggers that are new in Log4j2:
http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/async.html

They use the [LMAX Disruptor](http://lmax-exchange.github.com/disruptor/) under the hood which is a lock-free datastructure designed to reduce (or even eliminate) lock contention that is often a throughput bottleneck in multi-threaded scenarios.

[Performance](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/async.html#Performance) of AsyncLoggers is quite a bit better than AsyncAppender, especially when many threads are logging. Configuration is straight-forward, just use plain log4j2 configuration (which is different from log4j-1.x, btw) with a system property that makes all loggers AsyncLoggers.

You may also want to use the [RandomAccessAppender](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#RandomAccessFileAppender) that is new in Log4j2, as it is faster than the standard FileAppender. Both RandomAccessAppender and FileAppender, in combination with asynchronous logging, can be configured with `immediateFlush="false"` and all your events will still be flushed to disk (this was a major complaint I had about Log4j-1.x).

For your particular needs, logging 330MB in 20 sec, I would recommend starting with the default `AsyncLogger.RingBufferSize`, as it is quite large, with room for 256K events, but if this turns out to be insufficient it can be configured with a system property.

Comment: Thanks Remko i had read about it, and seems promising, but don't know what are the configuration to use it, will work on that and update all. Thanks.

Comment: I am facing problem configuring it, could you pls give references to configure the same either using xml or programmatically? Thanks.

Comment: What problem are you seeing? The manual page (1st link above) has good config examples. You can programmatically call System.setPropery in your main method.